# Trying to understand what is happening in this expression '${} | ${} '

Tags: javascript, reactjs, operators, bitwise-operators

I am trying to learn React and I want to understand the ins and outs of everything in this sample project.

```
const Meta = ({ site, title }) => {
  const siteTitle = get(site, 'title')
  title = title ? `${title} | ${siteTitle}` : siteTitle
```

Im assuming its comparing the main site title to individual post titles but I cant find anything online about what "|" means and I read the docs on '${}' but am still a little lost as to what it actually does.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), and the "|" is inside a string, so it's not possible to tell from this snippet, what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

| = or,
${} = das a variable displayed as a string

obv...next

Comment: I've been checking this thread daily for almost 3 years waiting for clarity on this subject. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

The '|' is a bitwise operator, imagine that you have the number 12 that corresponds to 1100 in binary and 10 that corresponds to 1010

if you try to compare

```
12 | 10
```

it's equal to compare 1100 and 1010 bit by bit, the result should be

```
1 1 0 0 // 12
1 0 1 0 // 10
-------
1 1 1 0 // 14
```

you can read more about binary operations [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_operators#Bitwise)

Answer (score 0):

**${}** This is the place where we include the expression or use javascript variables inside template literals. Template literals are enclosed by the backticks **``**. Imagine this is a normal string literal where we write but with the ease to use javascript expressions in between using ${Expression}.

**Example:**
let name = "John";

console.log(`Hello ${name}`).

Read More About This: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

2. The Pipe | Symbol stands for **OR** Any numeric operand in the operation is converted into a 32-bit number. The result is converted back to a JavaScript number.

Read More About JavaScript Bitwise Operators https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

Comment: Thank you so much, this was extremely helpful.

Comment: Always Welcome.